# display unique constraints errors message in html template dango

Tags: django, templates, unique-constraint

i'm trying to show `unique constraints` error in the template but i dont know to call back the error i know this works `{{form.errors}}` but it display the entire error messages in one place

```
class A(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField()
    dob = models.DateTimeField()


    class Meta:
        constraints = [
             models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['dob','name'],name=_('full_information'))
        ]
```

for the other fields i use this in my template

```
{% if form.name.errors %}
    {{form.name.errors}}
 {% endif %}
```

but i dont know what should i do for the `full_information` error message ?
thank you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with the [**`.non_field_errors`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.non_field_errors):

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% endif %}
```

This will list the errors that are *not* bounded by a specific field.

For more information, see the [*rendering fields manually* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).